# How to implement react-native-maps

Tags: ios, react-native, maps, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

Hope it can be silly question but as I'm new in react-native development, don't know how to get rid of this.

I want to put annotations on MapView & it seems [this tutorial from react-community](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps) is the best way to do it.

I followed the guidelines from [this tutorial](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/9/Build-a-Map-with-Custom-Animated-Markers-and-Region-Focus-when-Content-is-Scrolled-in-React-Native), created react-native project, it works perfectly.

I run these commands to link react-native-maps,

```
npm install react-native-maps --save
react-native link
```

It gives me following output,

[image]

But when I try this line,

```
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
```

it gives me this error, please find below screenshot.

[image]

I tried every thing from top to bottom, clean cache, restarted Metro Bundler every thing but didn't get success yet.

These tutorials I have searched to implement MapView in react-native,

1. https://medium.com/@gurusundesh/getting-started-with-react-native-mapview-5e0bd73aa602
2. https://codeburst.io/react-native-google-map-with-react-native-maps-572e3d3eee14
3. https://codedaily.io/tutorials/9/Build-a-Map-with-Custom-Animated-Markers-and-Region-Focus-when-Content-is-Scrolled-in-React-Native

Comment: Almost all tutorials on `react-native-maps` are wildly out of date with installation instructions. For example, [DO NOT USE `react-native link`](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md#important) is very clearly stated in the official project's installation docs. Always use the official docs first before following tutorials; especially when using native modules on React Native because of the fast changing environment. Start over and use the official installation instructions first and see if that works.

Comment: Why downvote? please specify

Comment: @MichaelCheng see the answer buddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been two days since I'm solving this issue. Finally got the solution.

Thanks to [this](https://www.codementor.io/uokesita/integrate-airbnb-google-maps-in-a-react-native-app-dxjp5p5ed) tutorial.

Solved the issue by changing dependencies in package.json manually:
Was:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native": "0.54.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.20.1"
  },
```

Changed to

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.51.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.20.1"
  },
```

Then ran `npm install` & `react-native-git-upgrade`.

My `App.js` code is here.

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          style={styles.map}
          region={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.015,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
          }}
        ></MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Finally I got the output like this.

[image]

Hope this works.

Comment: I'm getting blank map.

Comment: What issues you are facing, is there any error? try zoom In/out

Comment: I'm getting empty map with only google at bottom of screen

Comment: It means map is loading successfully, please set mapview initial region

Answer (score 0):

i guess only link wont work in map you need to follow this instruction too

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

Comment: make sure u have installed all required dependencies

Comment: steps mentioned there only run to problems/issues.